# Eventmachine:recieved ConnectionUnbound for an unknown signature

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

While I start server in Fedora 12, a client in Ubuntu 9.10.The client receive this error message.
But it's OK while I start server in Ubuntu 9.10, a client in Fedora 12.
I alreadt shutdown the FireWall.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is generated when an error occurs in one of the connection or protocol handler components.